# Excel 2010 prints older revision of a file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, printing, file-sharing, microsoft-excel-2010

Using Excel 2010 on Windows 7, editing a file on a shared folder. (The file server is running Windows Server 2008 R2.)

Opened the file to make some changes. Saved the changes. When I print, the Print Preview shows an older version of the file, and the old revision is sent to the printer.

Closing and reopening the file does not fix the problem. If I email the file to another computer and open it, the changes appear. So it appears that the file is being changed, but when Excel goes to print it, it is using an older revision that has been cached somewhere.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: apparently the document had a Print Area set that only included the old rows. While it appeared to be an older version of the document, it was in fact only the top part of the document.

Switching to the Page Layout tab and selecting Print Area > Clear resolved the problem.

There was no visual indication that a print area was set. I determine this by accessing the file on a different computer (same problem) and copying the file to the desktop (same problem), indicating that the document and not the computer or file server were at fault.

Comment: Since you were able to fix your own problem, feel free to accept it! :)

Comment: I will, after the mandatory two day waiting period expires.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running Office Diagnostics to see if this is a problem with your copy of Microsoft Office Excel 2010.

Comment: Office Diagnostics has been removed from Office 2010. You mean the "Repair" button in the Uninstall Programs Control Panel?

Comment: Yes, you're right.